How to import custom classes into a JasperSoft Studio?
I'm working with JasperSoft Studio 6.17.0. I need to create a report that using DTOs written by me in Java. I've imported the folder target with compiled DTOs into Jaspersoft's Java Build Path, and now I can choose my classes as types for parameter values. That is the behavioral I expect. But when I try to compile or preview the report, I recieve the error Errors were encountered while compiling report expressions class file: and MyDTO cannot be resolved to a type.
I've tried to fill the field Import in Parameter properties tab, but if I fill this field with direct link to a DTO, I recieve the error Only a type can be imported, MyDTO resolves to a package, and when I try to write link to a package there, a recieve the old error MyDTO cannot be resolved to a type. It seems illogical to me. Is it a JasperSoft bug? What should I do?
